# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on Xubuntu 16.04 64bits

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, c++14, qt5.6

I'm trying to follow the answer given in [QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on Ubuntu 15.04 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369480/qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-on-ubuntu-15-04-64bits)

on Xubuntu 16.04, where:

```
# ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysql* -ls
5624 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5757198 Abr 21 10:30 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Abr 21 10:29 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.20
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Abr 21 10:29 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20 -> libmysqlclient.so.20.2.1
4140 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4237408 Abr 21 10:30 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20.2.1
```

Here there are no `*_r` terminated files.

However, `make` seems to search for `*_r` terminated files:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:111: recipe for target '../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so' failed
make: *** [../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so] Error 1
```

From [What is difference between libmysqlclient.a and libmysqlclient_r.a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486584/what-is-difference-between-libmysqlclient-a-and-libmysqlclient-r-a) it seems just a link must be made between the two. Is this the correct approach? Should I do it manually like:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ln -s libmysqlclient.so.20.2.1 libmysqlclient_r.so.20.2.1
ln -s libmysqlclient.so.20 libmysqlclient_r.so.20
ln -s libmysqlclient.so libmysqlclient_r.so
ln -s libmysqlclient.a libmysqlclient_r.a
```

Or I'm missing some thing?

Comment: On Mac OSX the following might help `~/Qt/5.7/clang_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/include/" "LIBS += -L/usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/lib/"`.